# debug assertion failed: vector subscript out range in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, data-structures

I was asked to write a code to find the GCD of a very large number using arrays. However, my code is having some problems. It runs and seems to work for some pairs of numbers, but when I input certain pairs of numbers, such as: 24 and 18 or 52 and 18, the program gives out the error vector subscript out of range.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int num_cmp(const vector<int>& num1, const vector<int>& num2)
{

    /* function comparing two numbers whose digits are stored in vectors
    return -1 if smaller, 1 if larger, and 0 if equal */

    // compare number of digits first
    int len1 = num1.size(), len2 = num2.size();
    int msb = 0;
    while (num1[msb] == 0) {  // skip zeros
        --len1;
        ++msb;
    }
    msb = 0;
    while (num2[msb] == 0) {  // skip zeros
        --len2;
        ++msb;
    }
    if (len1 > len2)
        return 1;
    else if (len1 < len2)
        return -1;
    else {
        // if same length, compare digit by digit
        for (int i = 0; i < len1; ++i) {
            if (num1[i] > num2[i])
                return 1;
            else if (num1[i] < num2[i])
                return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void vec_intfromchar(vector<int>& a, const vector<char>& num)
{
    /* convert char vector to int vector
     two vectors are assumed to have same size  */
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        a[i] = num[i] - '0';
    return;
}

void print_vec(vector<int>& a)
{
    int start = 0;
    while (start < a.size() && a[start++] == 0); // skip zeros
    for (int i = start - 1; i < a.size(); ++i)
        cout << a[i];
    cout << "\n";

    return;
}

bool is_even(vector<int>& a)
{
    return a[a.size() - 1] % 2 == 0;
}

bool is_zero(vector<int>& a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        if (a[i] != 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

void substract(vector<int>& b, vector<int>& a)
{
    // b = b - a
    while (a.size() < b.size())
        a.insert(a.begin(), 0); // sign extension
    while (a.size() > b.size())
        b.insert(b.begin(), 0); // sign extension
    print_vec(a);
    print_vec(b);

    for (int i = b.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (b[i] < a[i]) {
            b[i] = b[i] - a[i] + 10;
            --b[i - 1];  // borrow
        }
        else
            b[i] -= a[i];
    }
    return;
}

void divide_by2(vector<int>& a)
{
    int dividend = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        dividend = dividend * 10 + a[i];
        a[i] = dividend / 2;
        dividend %= 2;
    }
    return;
}

void multiply_by2(vector<int>& a)
{
    int mult = 0, carry = 0;
    for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        mult = a[i] * 2 + carry;
        carry = mult / 10;
        a[i] = mult % 10;
    }
    return;
}

void addition(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b)
{
    // a = a + b

    while (a.size() < b.size())
        a.insert(a.begin(), 0); // sign extension
    while (b.size() < a.size())
        b.insert(b.begin(), 0); // sign extension

    int add = 0, carry = 0;
    for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        add = a[i] + b[i] + carry;
        carry = add / 10;
        a[i] = add % 10;
    }
    return;
}

vector<int> multiply(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b) {

    vector<int> acc(a.size() + b.size(), 0); // the final result

    for (int i = b.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        int mult = 0, carry = 0;
        vector<int> result(a.size() + 1, 0);   // middle result

        for (int j = a.size() - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            mult = a[j] * b[i] + carry;
            carry = mult / 10;
            // cout << "mult: " << mult << "\n";
            // cout << "carry: " << carry << "\n";
            result[j + 1] = mult % 10;
            if (j == 0)
                result[0] = carry;
        }


        // append zeros to the oprand
        for (int k = i + 1; k < b.size(); ++k)
            result.insert(result.end(), 0);
        
        // acumulation
        addition(acc, result);
        
    }
    return acc;
}



int main() {
    string str1, str2;
    cin >> str1 >> str2;
    vector<char> num1(str1.begin(), str1.end());
    vector<char> num2(str2.begin(), str2.end());

    // initial values for a, b, and ans
    vector<int> ans(1, 1);
    vector<int> a(num1.size());
    vector<int> b(num2.size());
    vec_intfromchar(a, num1);
    vec_intfromchar(b, num2);

    if (num_cmp(a, b) != -1)
        a.swap(b);  // set a to be the smaller one

    // Binary Algorithm for gcd
    while (!is_zero(a) && !is_zero(b)) {
        if (is_even(a) && is_even(b)) {
            multiply_by2(ans);
            divide_by2(a);
            divide_by2(b);
        }
        else if (is_even(a)) {
            divide_by2(a);
        }
        else if (is_even(b)) {
            divide_by2(b);
        }

        if (num_cmp(a, b) == 1)  // a > b
            a.swap(b);
        substract(b, a);    // b = b - a
    }
    vector<int> gcd = multiply(a, ans);
    print_vec(gcd);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried printing out the middle results to see where the problem is but I can't find it.

Comment: Debugger should pinpoint where you have out of bound access.

Comment: `print_vec` has out of bound access with empty vectors.

Comment: Happens in `substract` here: https://godbolt.org/z/Tr6Ea3bb5 Time to fire up that debugger and step through the code to see where it does something you're not expecting.

Comment: `multiply_by2` is broken. For instance, 2 * 9 = 8? `addition` has a similar problem with a lost carry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: BTW: many things are much easier if you store the least significant digit first.

Comment: I assume you're using Visual Studio based on the assertion. When you see that click retry to enter the debugger then use the call stack to get back to where it happens in your code. From there you can examine variables and such to see what went wrong.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/4dh3YMTs9

Comment: Consider `--b[i - 1];` when `i` is zero. (Again, things get easier if you reverse the representation.)